# Swift: How to use Hit Test & Bezier Paths to tap body parts?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, hittest

I'm trying to recognize where a user taps on a static image of a human body. They may tap the arm, leg, hand, etc and I'll show them that word in another language.

Image is static but I'd like it to work on both iPhones and iPads.

Any guidance appreciated. Thanks